# `edit()` that returns modal throws exception

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a simple button that's supposed to launch the modal [straight from the Modal example](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/2e6f05184ca667ec307c7a79a71df21c590ed992/packages/components/src/modal):

```
edit: withState( {
        isOpen: false,
    } )( ( { isOpen, setState } ) => (
        <div>
            <Button isDefault onClick={ () => setState( { isOpen: true } ) }>Open Modal</Button>
            { isOpen ?
                <Modal
                    title="This is my modal"
                    onRequestClose={ () => setState( { isOpen: false } ) }>
                    <Button isDefault onClick={ () => setState( { isOpen: false } ) }>
                        My custom close button
                    </Button>
                </Modal>
                : null }
        </div>
    ) ),
```

However, it throws an exception:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake I made was assuming that `Modal` existed on `editor`. I had this:

```
const {Button, Modal} = editor;
```

Correcting the import to the following, fixed this:

```
const {Button, Modal} = wp.components;
```

On the backend, when you register the component, you'll want to have `wp-components` as a dependency, of course:

```
wp_register_script(
    'recipe-block',
    ZRDN_PLUGIN_DIRECTORY_URL . $relativeScriptPath, // File.
    array( 'wp-components','wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-compose', 'wp-editor', 'wp-data','wp-element', 'underscore' ), // Dependencies.
    filemtime( ZRDN_PLUGIN_DIRECTORY . $relativeScriptPath ) // filemtime — Gets file modification time.
);
```